# VBA RemoveItem Unspecified Error for Active ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the following error:

> "Run-time error '-2147467259 (800040005)':
>
> Unspecified error.

When running the following code:

```
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cCont) = "ComboBox" Then
        Do While cCont.ListCount > 0 'Clear the list first
            'cCont.Selected = False
            'cCont.RowSourceType = Value
            cCont.RemoveItem (0)
        Loop
    End If
Next cCont
```

This is placed in a general code portion of a userform. The purpose of this is to delete the items that have been added previously by sub that is triggered by a change in the field value.

This code works for other ComboBoxes that are in the same userform, but the error is thrown when it gets to the ComboBox that I have my text cursor in.

I have checked that  RowSource = "" already. I'm not sure what else to try. Below is an image of the values associated with the ComboBox when the error occurs:

[image]

Comment: why not just use the `.Clear` method? `cCont.Clear` should do what you want.

Comment: The rowsource maybe blank at runtime. Check your code. I believe you are setting it at runtime. You may want to try and check it using `MsgBox cCont.RowSource` after the line `If TypeName(cCont) = "ComboBox" Then`

Comment: Was able to replicate this error only with a set up RowSource. You may try add one condition check to your code like  `If Not cCont.RowSource = "" Then
            cCont.RowSource = ""
        Else
            Do While cCont.ListCount > 0
                cCont.RemoveItem (0)
            Loop
        End If`

Comment: braX, thank you.. I could have sworn I tried that already and read somewhere that it wasn't working in Excel 2010... but it works.